# Replacing a regex in Total Commander multi rename tool

Tags: regex, total-commander

I am trying to replace all the strings which have:

```
Podcast 001 lksdf woejs sdklfjs wefsd
Podcast 002 sdfsd fgd
Podcast 003 fsdgw fdfs
Podcast 004 fdger fgdf
.
.
```

to

```
Podcast 001 - lksdf woejs sdklfjs wefsd
Podcast 002 - sdfsd fgd
Podcast 003 - fsdgw fdfs
Podcast 004 - fdger fgdf
.
.
```

So I've searched for:

```
Podcast [0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

and tried to replace it with:

```
Podcast [0-9][0-9][0-9] -
```

So I get:

```
Podcast [0-9][0-9][0-9] - etc.
```

which obviously is wrong.

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reference to capture group:

- search for: `(Podcast \d{3})`
- replace with: `$1 -`

Where `$1` is the content of group 1.

Comment: Thank you Toto! Which terms should I search in google in order to study this practice?

Comment: @dushkin: You'll find usefull informations here: https://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I need. Clearly expressed - concise answer. Thanks.